# Admob Banner at the top of the screen

Tags: swift, admob, constraints, banner, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to have the Admob banner at the top of the screen instead of the bottom. This is what i copied from the Admob Documentations.

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])
    }
```

I don't know how to work with contraints programmatically. Can anybody please help how I can put the banner at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .top,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: topLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
        ])
}
```